# More sophisticated file command for deep inspection?

Tags: files, file-format, file-command

Sometimes it seems that the standard [`file` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) (5.04 on my Ubuntu system) is not sophisticated enough (or I am just using it wrong, which could well be).

For example when I run it on an `.exe` file, and I am quite positive that it contains some archive, I would expect output like this:

```
$ improved-file foo.exe
foo.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
         .zip archive included (just use unzip to extract)
```

Other issues:

- It doesn't detect concatenations of different formats
- It doesn't detect common file formats, e.g. .epub, which is just a .zip container with some standardized .xml files etc. inside (`file` displays 'data')

An [example of such a .exe file](ftp://ftp.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/keyboards/pda/ta12b563enu.exe) containing an archive - I guessed some archive-formats and tried the corresponding unpack-commands with a trial'n'error approach - which worked in the end - but I would rather prefer a more auto-inspection oriented workflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of an all-in-one tool, but there are programs that can cope with a large array of files of a given category.

For example, [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) recognizes a large number of archive formats, so if you suspect that a file is an archive, try running `7z l` on it.

```
$ 7z l ta12b563enu.exe
…
Type = Cab
Method = MSZip
…
```

If you suspect that a file is an image, try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

```
$ identify keyboard.jpg.gz
keyboard.jpg.gz=>/tmp/magick-XXV8aR5R JPEG 639x426 639x426+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 37.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

For audio or video files, try `mplayer -identify -frames 0`.

If you find a file that `file` can't identify, you might make a feature request to the [author of your magic library](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).

Comment: awesome hints, had nearly forgotten `identify` and would have never thought of 7z handling other formats

Comment: Mentioned in `man mplayer`... *The wrapper script TOOLS/midentify.sh  suppresses the other MPlayer output and (hopefully) shellescapes the filenames.* ... I found mine in `/usr/share/mplayer`

Comment: When the extension is present but the actual type is so old that nothing will recognize it, sometimes https://filext.com comes in handy for historical references!

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with `file`.  It is doing just what it is supposed to be doing: examining the file based on the rules in the `magic(5)` file.  If you wish to come up with a generic way to identify these types of files, then you can submit new magic rules.  Read the manpage for `magic` for more information.

One thing I doubt `file` will ever do is "detect concatenations".  There is no way to determine when the next segment would start without scanning every byte in the file - something `file` does not do, or want to do.

Incidentally, to distinguish a epub file, you would need to detect the difference between it and an ear file, which uses the same basic structure.

Comment: What is an ear file? With .epub I would expect that `file` would detect at least .zip - I mean, .zip is really old and relatively common ... (`file` 5.04 just prints 'data' on my system)

Comment: Newer versions (both 10.10 and 11.04) show `Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract`.  An ear file is a jar file (which is packaged with zip) that includes a META-INF directory and a `/META-INF/application.xml` file.